# Is it possible to change the type of a standard JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

So is it possible to take an (Array, Date, ....) and change it into a different type? Let's take an Array for example:

```
var arr = [];
arr.__proto__ = NodeList.prototype;
arr instanceof Array // is now false
```

Yet if I do:
`dir(arr); // Array[0]`

So it's still technically an `Array` just not an instance?

How would I change it into a different type.

**Another Example:**

```
var str = new String('hi'); // I used new String to return mutable object
var str.__proto__ = Array.protoype;
dir(str); // String[2]
```

So technically still a `String`?

How would I go about changing it to another type (is it even possible)?

Comment: What is this `dir` function whose output you wish to change?

Comment: in the actual console it's global sorry

Comment: There are no classes in JS, so no "real type" of an object. The question then is what piece of information console.dir is picking up on. My guess is the constructor used to create the object.

Comment: @IMSoP hmm perhaps, if you want use that as an answer yet I won't mark as correct until I find out more on it, and also someone may know the true answer because were only going on by what it seems.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Somewhat abstract questions without a real use case become academic discussions without a lot of practical guidance or an ability to offer other potential solutions.

Comment: @IMSoP But where does the object keep this information about which constructor created it? Remember, we replaced its prototype link.

Comment: as far as i know JavaScript has only objects right now - even function aa(){} is an object there, so to change variable type just reinitialize it. Idk how it applies to builtin objects. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is an interesting question because doing `var x = new String("hi"); x.__proto__ = Array.prototype;` results in different behavior than `x = ["h","i"]`. For example, if you do `x.push("j")`, then `x.length` is still `2` when you might expect it to be `3`.

Comment: @PeterOlson - I didn't say it wasn't an interesting question to some.  I like to answer questions in the context of solving some real problem.  I don't participate in academic discussions so I was trying to see if there was an actual real world problem to solve here.  The weirdness you describe is exactly why I'm not sure this is a practical discussion at all.  I'll leave the academic discussion without a specified practical context to others I guess.

Comment: @PeterOlson it throws an Error becuase in `strings` the `length` property is readonly, and doing a push attempts to change the `length` property but thanks for that usecase

Comment: @EdwinReynoso It doesn't throw an error, it just fails silently.

Comment: @PeterOlson in chrome it does for me, I get an `Uncaught TypeError`

Answer (score 2):

This is a theory since I don't know the internal wokrings behind the `console.dir` function (which are browser-dependent anyways), but my guess is that `console.dir` displays `String[2]` instead of `Array[2]` because the [internal [[Class]] property](https://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) is `String`. You can test this out using the [`Object.prototype.toString` function](https://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2):

```
var x = new String("hi");
x.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
x instanceof Array // true
Object.prototype.toString.call(x) // "[object String]"
```

To answer your question about if it's possible to change the type of a JavaScript object (that is, in the context of this question, the internal [[Class]] property), according to the [ECMAScript 5 specification, section 8.6.2](https://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2):

> **NOTE** This specification defines no ECMAScript language operators or built-in functions that permit a program to modify an object’s [[Class]] or [[Prototype]] internal properties or to change the value of [[Extensible]] from false to true.

which means there is no way to do this using standard language constructs given in the specification, although there might or might not be some implementation-dependent extensions that make it possible.

Comment: Yes, that’s it. Forgot about the [[Class]] property. **Update:** Looks like ES6 removed [[Class]]. Now it’s using various other internal properties to determine the type of the object: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Cool, thanks, I didn't know about that. I need to read through the ES6 spec some time.